# when is the game fair?

Tags: probability

drop a coin on a grid of squares. the edges of the squares are three times the diameter of the coin. you win if the coin does not overlap.
What size grid square edge would make this fair game?

in my understanding, the probability of winning should be 0.5 for the game to be fair. but I don't where to start.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The chance of winnng only depends on the ratio between the square size and the coin size, which you have fixed at $3$.  It doesn't matter what the square size is specifically.  Now you can just change the payoff to make the game fair.  You should find what area within the square the center of the coin must land to avoid touching an edge.  That gives the winning probability.

Comment: @RossMillikan  the first question of this task was about finding the probability of winning and I did that, now I have to find the size of the square grid to make this game fair and I only know that the probability of fairness should be half.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you have fixed the ratio between the size of the grid and the diameter of the coin, then the scale doesn't matter.  You can adjust the payout, but not the probability of the outcome.

Comment: You should review how you derived the probability of winning that you calculated.  Somewhere you used the fact that the grid size is three times the diameter of the coin.  Make that ratio a variable and set the winning probability to $1/2$.  You should be able to find the ratio of grid size to coin diameter that satisfies that.